# Как в cssselect прописать отсутствие класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, cssselect

Добрый день. у меня возникла проблема:
допустим мне надо найти весь текст в блоке

```
<div class="ringtone"> </div>
```

тогда я пишу

```
text = str_html.cssselect('div.ringtone')
```

Но если мне надо вытащить

```
<div>
</div>
```

я не знаю что надо писать.
Вариант с `'div:nth-child(num)'` не подходит, так как теги с классом и теги без класса находятся на одном уровне.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А если так `div:not(.class)` ?

Comment: @nick_gabpe, нет, это будут все дивы, не имеющие данного класса, а ему нужны вообще без любых классов.

Comment: @Qwertiy , да, точно ,спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что помогло - с помощью сopy selector в Chrome достал
`div:nth-child(8)`
Спасибо большое всем за ответы

Answer (score 2):

В css работает так:

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll("div:not([class])")])
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('div:not([class]), div[class=""]')])
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class></div>
<div></div>
```